# How to find people who were born in summer from Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

My goal is to find people via Wikidata who were born in summer. What works for 1983 is this:

```
FILTER((?birth > "1983-06-20"^^xsd:dateTime) && (?birth < "1983-10-31"^^xsd:dateTime))
```

1. But I want it to filter for every year, i.e. not just 1983. How do I change the line?
2. If I want to add a year-span, like 1983 to 2000, how do I do it?

Comment: That seems to return people born in the winter. Are you sure your hemisphere calculation code is correct?

Comment: He actually makes a good point though. Joking aside, your query will not return "people born in summer" unless you also take into account _where_ they were born.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get people born after **20 June** and before **31 October** you can use one of these two variants:

```
SELECT ?item ?birth WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  ?item wdt:P569 ?birth .

  # variant 1: get from 20.06 to 30.06 and from 01.07 to 31.10
  FILTER(
    (month(?birth) = 6 && day(?birth) > 19) || 
    (month(?birth) > 6 && month(?birth) < 11)
  )

  # variant 2: get from 01.06 to 31.10 and remove from 01.06 to 19.06
  FILTER(month(?birth) > 5 && month(?birth) < 11)
  FILTER(!(month(?birth) = 6 && day(?birth) < 20))

} LIMIT 1000
```

If you want also to add a year-span (1983 - 2000) include these two filters before the others:

```
FILTER (?birth >= "1983-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)
FILTER (?birth <= "2000-12-31"^^xsd:dateTime)
```

Comment: Cool. I don't understand your code, though. How would you do it for people between 20 June and before 30 October?

Comment: I used `FILTER((((MONTH(?birth)) = 6) && ((DAY(?birth)) > 19)) || (((MONTH(?birth)) >6) && ((MONTH(?birth)) < 11)) || (((MONTH(?birth)) = 10) && ((DAY(?birth)) < 31)))` which seems to work.

Comment: @P.Dee, No, with this will get also 31.10 because of `(MONTH(?birth) >6 && MONTH(?birth) < 11)`. To get days from 20.06 to 30.10 you have to split the time into 3 parts: from 20.06 - 30.06 (part of June), from 01.07 - 30.09 (the whole months), and from 01.10 - 30.10 (part of October). So you have to change the second `OR` check in your code to `(MONTH(?birth) >6 && MONTH(?birth) < 10)`..

Comment: So you assemble the query step by step as in starting from day d of month x plus the full month x+1 plus till that day of month x+2. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: One last question: I have `SELECT ?personLabel ?personDescription WHERE { SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de". } }` and a lot of times the german Label is missing - along with the german Description. How do I make it fallback just to the english name but NOT the english description?

Comment: Never mind, I solved it with `SELECT ?pLabel ?pDesc WHERE { SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". ?person rdfs:label  ?pLabel. ?person skos:altLabel  ?pAlt. ?person rdf:label   ?pLabel. } SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de". ?person schema:description ?pDesc. } }`

Comment: In your first query you missed to specify what is `?person` in `?personLabel` and `?personDescription`, so just add: `?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .` before the SERVICE and it will work. I really don't know better way to describe the time-span including only the month and the day when the year is different.